# Ambari-Server on Docker Java install issues

Tags: docker, java, ambari

Today I hit a issues with my Ambari-Server install on a virtually blank system:

```
[root@<server>/]# ambari-server setup
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
Setup ambari-server
Checking SELinux...
SELinux status is 'disabled'
Customize user account for ambari-server daemon [y/n] (n)?
Adjusting ambari-server permissions and ownership...
Checking firewall status...
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table 'filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table 'nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

WARNING: iptables is running. Confirm the necessary Ambari ports are accessible. Refer to the Ambari documentation for more detai
OK to continue [y/n] (y)?
Checking JDK...
[1] OpenJDK 1.8.0
[2] OpenJDK 1.7.0 (deprecated)
[3] Custom JDK
==============================================================================
Enter choice (1):
Downloading JDK from http://birepo-build.svl/repos/IOP-UTILS/RHEL7/x86_64/1.1/openjdk/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz to /var/lib/ambari-1.8.0.tar.gz
jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz... 100% (56.5 MB of 56.5 MB)
Successfully downloaded JDK distribution to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz
Installing JDK to /usr/jdk64/
Installation of JDK has failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

JDK found at /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz. Would you like to re-download the JDK [y/n] (y)?
Re-downloading JDK from http://birepo-build.svl/repos/IOP-UTILS/RHEL7/x86_64/1.1/openjdk/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz
jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz... 100% (56.5 MB of 56.5 MB)
Successfully downloaded JDK distribution to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz
Successfully re-downloaded JDK distribution to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz
Installing JDK to /usr/jdk64/
Installation of JDK was failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

ERROR: Exiting with exit code 1.
REASON: Downloading or installing JDK failed: 'Fatal exception: Unable to install JDK. Please remove JDK, file found at /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-1.8.0.tar.gz and re-run Ambari Server setup, exit code 1'.     Exiting.`
```

Searching about I did a little investigation of my own as this is running on a Docker host. Hence the IPTables issue, this is due to it being within a Docker container and the NET_ADMIN capability for non-privileged containers. Unprivileged containers can't change their network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I've managed to figure out this issue my self.

First I found lots of links talking about manually installing the JDK, then repository issues and python script time-outs.
It was rather simple in the end, just needed to install the 'tar' package as it couldn't extract the files, once I did this, it ran through with no issue.

That's what I get for having a 'blank' install.

Answer (score 0):

Installing and run Ambari into Docker is a tricky thing. I've spent many days trying to make it all work. You can find here some hints about how to prepare centos7 docker based image for running Ambari server http://mixeddev.info/articles/2020/12/10/run-apache-ambari-hdp-hdf-in-docker.html